# Spring boot using Hashicorp Vault for Basic Authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, basic-authentication, hashicorp-vault

I was playing around with a little Spring Boot application that uses Hashicorp Vault. I wanted to implement Basic Authentication and wondered if I could keep the users details in the vault.  There will never be many users for this app perhaps 5 - 10 different users.  As the vault is used for other things I wanted to avoid having to keep the users in a separate database somewhere.

The vault has kv (v1) engine which contains the username, a Bcrypt encoded password and the Roles of the user.

When a user logins into this app it does a lookup for the provided username in the vault and compares the password provided (which is BCrypt encoded) with the encoded password string from the vault and if authenticated collects the Roles etc etc...

Something like this.

I include this into my POM file

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.vault</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-vault-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

A simple User POJO

```java
public class VaultBasicUser {
    private String password;
    private String roles;

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(String roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

My Custom Authentication Provider

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
public class BasicVaultAuthentication implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private VaultTemplate vaultTemplate;
    
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        
        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        
        VaultResponseSupport<VaultBasicUser> vaultResponse = vaultTemplate.read("myApp/users/" + name, VaultBasicUser.class);
        
        String vaultSecret = vaultResponse.getData().getPassword();
        
        if (vaultSecret != null) {
            if (BCrypt.checkpw(password, vaultSecret)) {
        
                String vaultRoles = vaultResponse.getData().getRoles();
                        
                List<GrantedAuthority> roles = new ArrayList<>();
                
                String[] stringOfRoles = vaultRoles.split(",");
                for (String singleRole : stringOfRoles) {
                    roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(singleRole.replaceAll("\s", "")));
                }
                
                UserDetails principal = new User(name, password, roles);
                Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, password, roles);
                return auth;
            }
            else {
                log.info("Incorrect Credentials (Password)");
                return null;
            }
        }
        else {
            log.info("Incorrect Credentials (User Not found in Vault)");
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class
        );
    }
```

This works, however when testing I noticed that each transaction's authentication was taking about 375ms to process.  I wondered if I change my strategy a little if I could reduce the 375ms for the authentication.

So I thought perhaps I could populate an InMemoryUserDetailsManager at startup and then the users will be in memory so the authentication part won't rely on API calls to the Vault for each transaction thereby reducing the time for authentication.

I tried something like this:

```java
@Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(PasswordEncoder encoder) {
        
        Collection<UserDetails> allUsers = new ArrayList();

        log.info("Collecting MyApp users from Vault: " + vaultConfig.getUrl());

        // ***** Get All users from Vault HERE ***** 
            VaultEndpoint vaultEndpoint;
            try {
                vaultEndpoint = VaultEndpoint.from(new URI(vaultConfig.getUrl()));
                VaultTemplate vaultTemplate = new VaultTemplate(vaultEndpoint, new TokenAuthentication(vaultConfig.getToken()));
                List<String> vaultUsers = vaultTemplate.list("myApp/users");

                for (String vaultUser : vaultUsers) {
                    VaultResponseSupport<VaultBasicUser> vaultResponse = vaultTemplate.read("myApp/users/" + vaultUser, VaultBasicUser.class);
                    String password = vaultResponse.getData().getPassword();
                    String vaultRoles = vaultResponse.getData().getRoles();
                    
                    log.info("Adding User: [" + vaultUser + ", " + password + ", " + vaultRoles + "]");
                    allUsers.add(User.withUsername(vaultUser).password(password).roles(vaultRoles).build());
                }

            } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
                log.error("Unable to read in MyApp users from Vault: " + ex.getMessage());
                log.info("Adding some Default Users...");
                allUsers.add(User.withUsername("myapp_admin").password(encoder.encode("adminPassword")).roles("MYADMIN").build());
                allUsers.add(User.withUsername("myapp_poweruser").password(encoder.encode("powerUserPassword")).roles("MYELEVATED").build());
                allUsers.add(User.withUsername("myapp_client").password(encoder.encode("clientPassword")).roles("MYUSER").build());
            }
        } else {
            log.info("Authentication configured for [" + authType.getType() + "] - Not connecting to Vault!");
        }

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(allUsers);
    }
```

However, when I run the same test the authentication still takes approximately 370ms.  Is my thinking totally wrong here?  Shouldn't retrieving the user details from memory be faster than getting them from the vault directly?  Have I got a problem somewhere else?

**Edit #1:** Added some screenshots of using the Profiler in Netbeans.

This image is of using the BasicVaultAuthentication Custom Authentication Provider (This is where the call to the Vault happens right before the BCrypt.checkpw)

[image]

This picture is using the InMemoryUserDetailsManager However the authentication should be against the users that have been loaded into memory.

[image]

Comment: How are you measuring? Did you time the two implementations of `AuthenticationProvider` or end-to-end request-response time?

Comment: Ahh good question.  I did nothing as elaborate as that.  I was simply looking at the response time in postman when I ran my tests against myApp.  The reason I am looking at the authentication is that if I turn off all authentication the transactions complete in under 10ms.  When I enable Basic Authentication directly to the vault I see request-response times of 375ms and when I use the InMemoryUserDetailsManager and not direct calls to Vault I see very similar request-response times of 370ms.  I thought it would be more with an InMemory data structure.

Comment: Your screenshots suggests a <1% difference.

Comment: @ValerijDobler - Exactly.  That is what I am saying.  When making the call to a Vault on a remote machine compared to making the call to an InMemoryUserDetailsManager shouldn't the call to memory be significantly quicker than the call to the Vault?

Comment: Is the call being made at the time of the recording? Can you observe it at the serving side?